# Как посчитать количество цифр вещественного числа без точки, т.е. только цифры?

Tags: java

Можете подсказать, как посчитать количество цифр вещественного числа без точки, т.е. только цифры?

Например, в консоль вожу `25,2525`. Если считать длину через `length`, то он будет считать всё вместе с запятой, а мне нужно без неё.

Comment: Как задано вещественное число? Что такое количество цифр вещественного числа? Сколько цифр должно быть у числа (0.1 + 0.2)?

Comment: ну вот, например в консоль вожу 25,2525. если считать длину через lenght, то он будет считать всё вместе с запятой, а мне нужно без неё.

Comment: Удали запятую и посчитай.

Comment: я прописываю число в консоль через Scanner, а не заранее

Comment: Используйте Math.floor()

Comment: @Miron как тут оно поможет?

Comment: @Эникейщик тем, что теперь задача преобразуется в задачу нахождения кол-ва цифр целого числа. А эта задача уже 100 раз решена.

Comment: @Miron math.floor(25.2525) даст 25.0. Как это поможет в решении задачи?

Comment: @Эникейщик ((int) 25.0) = 25. Я думал, что это само собой разумеющееся

Comment: @Miron Вы вопрос читали?

Comment: @Эникейщик да, а что? То, что после запятой - отсечено. Остается только посчитать оставшиеся цифры

Comment: @Miron где там сказано, что то, что после запятой, нужно отбрасывать? Нужно не учитывать запятую, а цифры после нее отбрасывать никто не просил.

Comment: @Эникейщик Тогда я действительно неправильно понял вопрос

Comment: @Miron а для нахождения количества цифр до запятой к целому виду приводить необязательно.

Answer (score 0):

```
String inString = Float.toString(44.9003f);
if(inString.charAt(inString.length() - 1) == '0'){
    if(inString.charAt(inString.length() - 2) != '.' && inString.charAt(inString.length() - 2) != ','){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    System.out.println(inString.length() - 2);
} else {
    System.out.println(inString.length() - 1);
}
```